# Fullcalendar maxTime into next day

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to set a maxTime into the next day? I want to do something like 3am to 2:59am.

I was hoping the following would do the trick. It renders the timeslots correctly but doesn't display any events after midnight

```
    minTime: "02:00:00",
    maxTime: "26:59:59",
```

http://jsbin.com/toyamimexe/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this (fullCalendar v2.6.1) by setting:

```
maxTime: "1.02:59:00"
```

as fullCalendar is using moment duration

Reference: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: It seems there is some change, because for FullCalendar 4.0, the format is maxTime='29:59:00'

Answer (score 0):

5 years later :)

There is some changes in the framework, because it works for me with the **version 4.0 of FullCalendar**.

So, my code (VueJs and Quasar) is

```
  minTime='07:00:00'
  maxTime='29:59:00'
```

wich displays day from 6h in the current day to 6h of the next day.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not possible. After 23:59:59, the date rolls over to the next date. You can't display events that technically fall under a date, in the previous date slot in fullcalendar.